# My android app stops recording GPS data when screen goes to home after being idle

Tags: android, android-activity, gps

I have this activity that is recording GPS positions along a route.  I am not sure what the processes or methods I need to keep this alive even after my screen shuts off and the security trace thingy comes up.  It seems the stop recording happens, right now I have two buttons that handle a boolean that starts recording or not.  I am not sure what I have to do or what event I have to trap to make sure my state of the program remains constant even if another call comes in, or something else happens... (Do I have to make it a service?!)

Really I only care about the gps recorder still recording after the screen goes dark cause phones been idle.  Before I put that security patttern draw thingy it would work, but now that its on something else is going on where my code state is getting kind of hosed.  Whats this wake lock I hear about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: yes, u need a service

Complicated one: Activity dies as soon as its out of focus, so if you want to continue recording data, you need to make it a service.

Comment: ... and use a Wake lock to keep service running even if device is sleeping.

Comment: can that wake lock work to protect from it dying when phone locks screen?  I don't need a service yet its a personal data logging app so I don't plan on it swapping activities by my screen shutting off sure did kill it...

Comment: yes, you can do that, but it'll kill the battery even faster. That's called a commplete wake lock

Comment: so service is my only choice?  I dont understand some programs run with a front end (Activities and views) but if u pop off them they have a icon in the status bar as they are still running so it must turn on a service on exit and on resume stop the service and let the main activity take over?

Comment: Activity is just the view, the actual work is done entirely by the service.